# applying loops functions to equations

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is a super basic question but I always struggle to get loops to run in R and output correctly. I have an initial value of 180000 and I want to apply a loop that calculates a growth over 50 years of 0.5% each year. I hope to create a vector or from this so I can index it later. Thanks for any help!

Comment: update** in R programming, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a vector, then here it is

```
v <- 18000*(1+0.005)**(0:49)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question because you don't mention a language but here is a java example:

```
int a = 180000;
for(int year=0; year<50; year++) {
  a *= 1.005;     // add 0.5% each year
}
```

Not sure what you mean with the vector part.

Comment: OP is using R, and wants each iteration in a separate element of an array